How to manage ActiveMQ Artemis server through Core protocol
I'm trying to manage a remote Apache Artemis 2.35.0 through the CORE protocol connection. I don't want to connect to the broker through HTTP.
The docs for usage of CORE protocol is quite limited.
How can I do management tasks like getting all queues and moving message between queues? I've found the interfaces like QueueControl but can't figure out how to get a usable object to call those methods on.

When you use management messages you don't get an object on which you can invoke methods. You simply add the right properties (i.e. name of the resource, operation, and parameters) to the message and send it. This is outlined in the management documentation. Also, keep in mind that the core API is documented here.

Your question may be closed due to the phrase, "How can I do management tasks like..." If you were to just ask, "How can I move message between queues?" then a clear, direct answer could be provided and would likely be much more useful to the community. As it stands now the question lacks focus.

You should look into the management documentation.
There is also relevant code in the examples repo.
